# Strategy for Immutable Classes - Is this a contradiction?

Tags: java, immutability

The [strategy for defining an immutable class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) contains 2 points:

1. Mark the field as private and final
2. Don't provide setters

My point of confusion is: **when I have marked the field as `private final`, what extra safety does omitting setters will give?**

Since the field is private, it cannot be accessed outside the class without a class method. But since it is also final, it cannot be modified after it has been initialized.

Suppose, in the following class, if I do not initialize my field at the 2 places highlighted, then compiler will give me error that final blank field has not been initialized which means **marking the filed as final, won't let me construct an object without initializing the final field which means only 1 value of such a field will exist after object creation**

```
class MyImmutable {
  private final int field1; // either initialze here

  MyImmutable() {
     this.field1 = ... ; // or here
  }
}
```

Comment: You fail the realise the linked article is a recipe, where the first step (not the second!) is _"Don't provide "setter" methods"_, then the second step (not the first!) is _"Make all fields `final` and `private`"_. In that order it makes a lot more sense than the order you present in your question. Those four steps listed in the article provide an increasing sense of immutable.

Comment: `private final` doesn't ensure immutability. The type `MyImmutable` could be composed of a mutable object, which setters delegate to (common when decomposing existing code). Setters are fine as long as they don't mutate state. Your example is only justified due to it being composed of only primitive types. If `MyImmutable` was composed of a mutable reference type, it's a different story.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Which is addressed by the other two steps in the linked article.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, it's addressed by the 4th step. But the statement was clear about it's definition of "setter". The following statements, such as marking fields `private final`, would make the 1st statement pointless. But it's definitely the point they're trying to get across: "*There are two setter methods in this class. ... The second one, invert, can be adapted by having it create a new object instead of modifying the existing one.*" - One could say they're exhausting similar points, I'd personally say they're being explicit about a single point (immutability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The article is just being explicit about the properties of an immutable type.

They quoted the word "setter" and followed it with a precise defintion. The exact quote states:

> Don't provide "setter" methods — **methods that modify fields or objects referred to by fields**

`private final` doesn't always ensure immutability. In your example, `private final` is sufficient because `field1` is a primitive type.

Take a closer look at the quote:

> **methods that modify** fields or **objects referred to by fields**

If `MyImmutable` was composed of a mutable type, setters could delegate calls to them, resulting in `MyImmutable` being mutated, regardless of whether fields within `MyImmutable` were marked `private final` or not.

Here's an example of using `private final`, but the type consists of a mutable type, which a setter delegates calls to:

```
@Immutable
class Person {
    private final Identity identity; // Identity is a mutable type

    public void changeNameTo(String name) {
        identity.changeNameTo(name); // private final can't prevent this
    }
}

@Mutable
class Identity {
    private String name;

    public void changeNameTo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Which is a common tactic when [decomposing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science)) existing code.

Comment: I was always under the impression that a setter does nothing but a dumb assignment of some external value to a local field value. Just out of curiousiy, would we call `changeNameTo` a setter too? There could always be several methods that would render your class mutable but such methods were not in context here.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan That's exactly what this is doing, especially if a compiler was told to inline `Identity#changeNameTo` (would would result in bytecode similar to if the code from `Identity#changeNameTo` was plopped right back inside `Player#changeNameTo`): all the behavior does is adjust a property's state. The only difference here is the delegation, which doesn't change the philosophy.